# I lost my work when my OpenID was checked

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-openid

After typing in an answer to a question, Stack Overflow ran off to verify my ID with Open ID, opening a new page that asked the appropriate questions, letting Google verify who I was etc...

And then nothing!

My text was gone (*sigh*).

Comment: And here I was, thinking this was the first case of a SO related firing :D

Comment: if(openIDChecksOut()){ fireEmployee(); }

Answer (score 2):

That's why I do a select and copy whenever I leave the page.  If my imperishable words perish, I can always paste them back in again.

Comment: We are working with Stack Overflow here, not Lotus Notes. I expect better.

Comment: You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: @Earlz:  I may have lower expectations of any web-based application than you do.

Comment: Although this answer is not very satisfying, it is in fact the most correct response.  It's something that you should train yourself to do.  It's not uncommon for this to occur, and the sooner you pick up the habit, the less frustrated you will become.

Answer (score 0):

We now save drafts for anonymous users upon click of LOG IN and re-associate them after they have logged in.